# jquery datepicker duplicate date for November 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using a jquery date picker for my site. It works perfect except November 3 2013 is duplicated causing the month of November to be off. The other months do not have any issues. Does anyone know of a fix or seen this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="ui.datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a link to the datepicker.min.js

http://www.headlightrestore.net/ui.datepicker.min.js

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use a newer version of both libraries? jQuery 1.2.6 is pre-historic.

Comment: I have tried jquery 1.8.3 but that did not fix the problem. I tried jquery 1.9.1 and that caused the calendar to not appear.

Comment: Did you also update the jQuery UI library?

Comment: Thanks. I ended up updating to the latest versions. It took a bit more work but it was worth it.